# Can't remove the sidebar in SB Admin Bootstrap Template

Tags: html, css, templates

I want to remove the sidebar, I tried deleting the nav content but still the sidebar is still there. The sidebar is under wrapper class and there is not separate class for sidebar.

Comment: Please provide your code

Answer (score 2):

Remove all sidebar components and then add the following to the css media:

`margin-left: 0` to `#page-wrapper`